# std::vector: How to return pointer to object in vector c++

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

I'm trying to convert a vector iterator to the object pointer in the function below:

```
std::vector<some_object> some_objects;

some_object* getsome(int index)
{
    if( index < ledges.size() && index >= 0)
    {
        return &(*some_objects[index]);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

However the compiler throws an error : "no match for 'operator*." What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: What is `some_objects`? You probably either want `return &some_objects[index]` or `return some_objects[index]`, depending on what `some_objects` is.

Comment: Just `return &some_objects[index]`, usually.

Comment: The proper way to handle this is to reconsider your design. A vector is permitted to copy/delete its members, so a pointer to one of its members is not guaranteed to remain valid. My guess is that you have some code that accepts a pointer as an argument, and you want to apply it to the contents of a vector; in that case you should consider which pieces of code own the various objects, and which developers own the various pieces of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the vector is holding objects of type `some_object` but not `some_object *`. You are trying to dereference a non-pointer type and compiler is complaining about it. Try -

```
return  &(some_objects[index]);
```

or

```
return &(some_objects.at(index));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` operator of your `some_objects` vector has return type `some_object&` (a reference), so to get a pointer to it you just need to use the `&` operator directly on that:

```
return &some_objects[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_object* getsome( std::vector<some_object>::size_type index)
{
   return ( index < some_objects.size() ? &some_objects[index] : NULL );
}
```